# How to generate *.ipa file

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, ipa

First I apologise for my english.
could you help me with small problem :slight_smile:
I want to create *.ipa file from ionic project, but in indentify area xcode told me that I must "Fix Issue".
And if I click on the fix issue, so xcode show me modal window with text An App ID identifier "com.xxxxx.xxxxxx" is not available please enter the different sting, but I need use defined string, concretely defined string in "Bundle indentifier".

What can i do? Could somebody help me width this problem?

I try to change "Bundle indentifier" e.g. com.xxxxx.xxxxxx1. I add only 1 to end and it works but I need use Bundle identfier without 1 number in the end of bundle identifier string.

And one thing under Team item I have text "No provisionig profiles found", but if i add 1 to the end of identifier bundle and click to Fix Issue this text "No provisionig profiles found" disappear.

Thank you for any advice,

best regards Peter

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an apple developer account with enough access to do the following:

- Create a development/production certificate
- Create provisioning profiles based on the above certificate

In order to be able to build an *.ipa file you need to do the following:

1. Create the development/production certificate
2. Add the UDID of all devices on which you want to run the *.ipa install
3. Based on your choice you need to create a provisioning profile for either Development or Ad Hoc distribution.
4. Archive your project
5. Time to create your distribution:

   - if you chose Development, it's rather straight forward, just follow the steps (disable "Rebuild from bitcode" for faster build) - after this you can e-mail the build, but the build will need to be installed through iTunes on a device whose UDID you've added above
   - if you chose Ad Hoc, you need to upload your build to a remote HTTPS location, along with the corresponding manifest (*.plist) file (if you need further instructions on this, I can help, don't want to go into too many details if this is not what you want)

The "Fix issue" shows every time when your device UDID has not been added to the provisioning profile of the app bundle ID that's been set within the app.